# Add dynamically controls to asp placeholder in addition to controls which already exist in it

Tags: c#, asp.net

Add dynamically controls to asp placeholder in addition to controls which already exist in it ?
how to add them?

for example - on page load I added to textboxs and labels to placeholder on button click I need to add additionally one more textbox.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the methods like Add, AddAt, Remove, RemoveAt, Clear to change the controls collection available on the PlaceHolder control.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection_methods.aspx) for an elaborate explaination of the methods mentioned above.